# Why is the following code outputting [<__main__.Book object at 0x00000207911F1FD0>]. While I expect output of list of books I added

Tags: python, oop

This is a fairly simple code that adds books and their info to the list. Yet I recieve unexpected output.

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, name, author, code):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
        self.code = code
        self.available = True

class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.books = []

    def addBook(self, book):
        self.books.append(book)


algebra = Book('Algebra for beginners', 'Albert Einstein', 123)
lib = Library()

lib.addBook(algebra)
print(lib.books)
```

Comment: It is indeed a list with one book. If you want "nice-looking" output, you'd need to override the `__repr__` method

Answer (score 1):

Because the type is Book followed by its identifier. If you want something human readable use `__repr__` (str representation).

Try

```py
class Book:
    def __init__(self, name, author, code):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
        self.code = code
        self.available = True

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.__class__.__name__} ({self.name} by {self.author})>"


class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.books = []

    def addBook(self, book):
        self.books.append(book)

    # snake_case for python functions/methods
    def search_author(self, author):
      books_by_author = [b for b in self.books if b.author == author]
      for book in books_by_author:
          if book.available:
              print(f"Available: Title: {book.name}, code: {book.code}")
          else:
              print(f"Unavailable: Title: {book.name}, code: {book.code}")

algebra = Book('Algebra for beginners', 'Albert Einstein', 123)
other = Book('Another book by Einstein', 'Albert Einstein', 124)

other.available = False

lib = Library()

lib.addBook(algebra)
lib.addBook(other)

lib.search_author("Albert Einstein")
```

Comment: What if I want to add another method and also print it. For example searchAuthor() that’ll loop over self.books list and return the first match in self.author. How do I need to modify __repr__ to both print self.books and SearchAuthor() ? I don’t get __repr__ by much.

Comment: That __repr__ belongs to Book. The functionality you're speaking of belongs to Library.

edit: To elaborate on ``__repr__`` more, you would not implement it as a way of returning a matching iteration. ``__repr__`` is particuarly useful for debugging, and you can override it with ``__str__`` for the end-user. On your API you may differentiate it with ``repr(lib.books[0])`` and ``str(lib.books[0])`` However, your class is not a ``str``, you would normally be operating on its attributes.
You would not modify ``__repr__`` or ``__str__``. I updated my answer for another aproach.

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways to go here:

Method 1 - asForceBru suggests in the comment, add a `__repr__` method to the `Book` class, which returns a string:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, name, author, code):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
        self.code = code
        self.available = True
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name+", "+self.author+", code: "+\
            str(self.code)+", available: "+str(self.available)
```

so that the output of `print(lib.books)` is:

```
[Algebra for beginners, Albert Einstein, code: 123, available: True]
```

OR

Method 2 - add a `__str__` method to both `Book` *and* `Library` classes:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, name, author, code):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
        self.code = code
        self.available = True
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name+", "+self.author+", code: "+\
            str(self.code)+", available: "+str(self.available)

class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.books = []
    def __str__(self):
        info_string = ""
        for b in self.books:
            info_string += str(b)+"\n"
        return info_string
    def addBook(self, book):
        self.books.append(book)
```

so that now the output of `print(lib)` is:

```
Algebra for beginners, Albert Einstein, code: 123, available: True
```

As you see, the call to `print()` and output is slightly different.